# How many people actually visit MPs surgeries?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

In the United Kingdom, a [political surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgery_%28politics%29) is a series of one-to-one meetings that a member of parliament may have with his or her constituents.  A typical constituency has in the order of 75k residents.  Are there any statistics on the contact rate of such surgeries?  What fraction of the population has ever visited such a surgery?  Is it a small active group that visits surgeries frequently, or are there rather many people that occasionally reach out to their MP and visit the surgery?

Comment: there was a Channel 5 series MPs Behind closed doors, but it gives annecdotes not stats

Comment: The surgery isn't the only avenue for MPs to interact with constituents.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, consider the [MP for Croydon central.](https://www.sarah-jones.org/surgery/)

She holds weekly surgeries, for two hours, 20 minutes per consultation. So she can see a maximum of 6 people per week, 300 people per year.

It is likely that not all the surgery slots are fully booked, so you may want to estimate a lower value than this. Moreover, some people will be "return customers". So let us estimate 150 individuals per MP per year.

Croydon central is a fairly typical outer London constituency. Not all MPs continue to hold surgeries. But extrapolating from this single data point one might expect 10000--100000 people to visit an MP's surgery in the course of a year, or about 0.1% of the UK population.